# Drawing ROC curve after building a manual bagging classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn to manually build a bagging classifier. I need to do so because I have three subsets of data and I need to train a classifier on each one. So what I basically did is creating three `RandomForestClassifier` classifiers and trained each one on the subset. Then given a testset, I do the following to find the ROC AUC:

```
        probas2 = estimators[2].predict_proba(X_test)
        probas3 = estimators[3].predict_proba(X_test)
        probas4 = estimators[4].predict_proba(X_test)

        probas = probas2[:,1] + probas3[:,1] + probas4[:,1]
        probas = probas / 3.0

        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probas)
        roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

However what I need is to do 3-folds cross validation and then draw ROC curve and output AUC. So basically I keep track of `fpr`, `tpr` and `roc_auc` after each fold using lists like this:

```
folds_auc.append(roc_auc)
folds_fpr.append(fpr)
folds_tpr.append(tpr)
```

The problem is that after each fold `fpr` and `tpr` are arrays of different lengths, so I can't just sum them and divide by 3 in order to draw the ROC curve. I want to draw the ROC curve and I can't figure out how to do so. How can I solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to combine the results of cross-validation folds before calculating the `roc_auc`, and then calculate the performance on all. That's what you have to do if you're doing a leave one out cross-validation, but you can do a similar schema here.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/how-do-you-generate-roc-curves-for-leave-one-out-cross-validation) it's more explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from the examples: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_roc_crossval.html